# The image of a bounded sequence, by a continuous function, has convergent subsequence

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X=(X,|\cdot|)$ be a Banach, $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X$ a bounded sequence and $f: X \longrightarrow X$ a continuous function. Then $f(x_n)$ has a convergente subsequence.

That's true?

I have seen a similar result for the case where $ X $ has finite dimension. But I did not get proof (or give counterexample) for the case where $ X $ may not have finite dimension.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458111/example-of-a-metric-space-where-heine-borel-theorem-does-not-hold

In an infinite dimensional Banach space this does not hold, take $f$ to be identity map

Comment: The statement is false and it is equivalent to saying that each bounded sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: It is true, however, if $f$ is a compact linear operator. In fact this property, if we let the sequence $\left\{x_n\right\}$ vary, characterizes compact operators amongst linear operators.